# Trouble with v-for="product in products"

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, v-for

First of all, I'm sorry for my english, not my maternal language. Secondly, there is my github : https://github.com/CapitaineBarbarossa/test-carousel
So, my problem is that I want to make a dynamic carousel so I use v for= product in product. As you can see, no image appears but when you press F12 to inspect, all appear and all is good and stay good if you leave the dev tool. But if you refresh the page, the images disappears again. And I really don't know how to fix this issue.

With my gratitude, I wish you a good day!

I tried to make a dynamic carousel but the images don't appear like they should.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. That is not a vue issue. That is a CSS issue. All carousel div's width & height is zero because you used `position absolute` property.

```
.carousel__body .carousel__slider__item .item__3d-frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.carousel__body .carousel__slider__item .item__3d-frame__box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: var(--box-border);
  background: var(--box-bg);
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}


.contain {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's not as I want with this new parameters, still bug, but I see where I have to search! Thank you very much!